# How to make so when a statement is true or false it prints something such as "you are a new patient"

Tags: python, pycharm

im very new to coding so i want to know how to do this, sorry if its a newbie question
i want so that where its "str(new_patient) + "" says "you are a new patient!" but instead i got True as a result, the phrase should look like " His name is John Smith he is 20 years old and is a new patient

```
name = "John Smith"
age = 20
new_patient = True
if new_patient:
    print("a new new_patient")
else:
    print("you are not a new patient")


print("His name is " + name + " he is " +str(age) + " old and is a "+ str(new_patient) + "")
```

Comment: ```new_patient="a new new_patient"```. You need to change to value of ```new_patient``` to those which you print

Comment: The "new_patient" is a variable name and the boolean object "True" is its value. 
When you use the function str(), it will use the built-in function __str__() of the "new_patient" and return the value "True" of the "new_patient" as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the text you want to display in a string like this:

```
age = 20
new_patient = True

new_text = ""
if new_patient:
    new_text = "a new patient"
else:
    new_text = "not a new patient"

print("His name is " + name + " he is " + str(age) + " old and is " + new_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should save the str in a variable then you print the value from the variable.
Here I save the string in variable:new_patient.then I use the variable in the print
phrase

````
name='Caio'
age = 20
new_patient = True
if new_patient:
    new_patient="a new patient"
    
else:
   new_patient = " not a new patient"


print("His name is " + name + " he is " +str(age) + " years old and is "+ str(new_patient) + "")```
````

Answer (score 0):

```py
name = "John Smith"
age = 20
new_patient = True
if new_patient:
    new_patient = "a new new_patient"
else:
    new_patient = "you are not a new patient"

print("His name is " + name + " he is " + str(age) + " old and is a " +new_patient)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tually need to assign the strings to `new_patient`. If you `if/else` statement, you just print the string and the value of `new_patient` is unchanged. So `True` is printed.

```
name = "John Smith"
age = 20
new_patient = True
if new_patient:
    new_patient="a new new_patient"
else:
    new_patient="you are not a new patient"


print("His name is " + name + " he is " +str(age) + " old and is a "+ str(new_patient) + "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using f-string (Python 3.6+)

```py
name, age, new_patient = "John Smith", 20, True
print(f"His name is {name} he is {age} old and {'is a new patient' if new_patient else 'you are not a new patient'}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using f-strings in python 3.6+ and a tuple-ternary trick makes this clean. I would also suggest adding gender here, and (not shown) limit choices:

```
#!/bin/python3.8
def patient(name: str, age: int, gender: str, is_new: bool) -> None:
    print(f"{name} is a {age} year old {gender} who is a{('n existing', ' new')[is_new]} patient.")

patient("John Smith", 20, "male", True)

# prints: John Smith is a 20 year old male who is a new patient.
```